# How can I call a string resource via a name stored in a variable?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, resx

I want to call a string type resource inside a .resx by its name which is stored in a variable.

Let's say that I have a `DataGridView1` with these columns:

```
| Kiwi | Apple | Grape | 'these are the columns name
```

I have a `Core.resx` to store my resources:

```
| Name      | Value       | Comment | 'note how the name of the resource
| DGV_Kiwi  | Hairy Kiwi  |         | 'is "DGV_" & column.Name
| DGV_Apple | Red Apple   |         |
| DGV_Grape | White Grape |         |
```

When loading `DataGridView1` I want to change the header to the value of the resource file. Of course, I can do it with something like:

```
DataGridView1.Columns(0).HeaderText = My.Resources.Core.DGV_Kiwi
DataGridView1.Columns(1).HeaderText = My.Resources.Core.DGV_Apple
DataGridView1.Columns(2).HeaderText = My.Resources.Core.DGV_Grape
```

But I'm lazy and I have a lot more columns in my real project. So I want to do this with a loop.

This is the first thing I've tried :

```
For Each Col As DataGridViewColumn In Me.DataGridView1.Columns
    Col.HeaderText = My.Resources.Core.Col.Name
Next
```

Of course, this does not work:

> Col is not a member of Core

I have also tried this:

```
For Each Col As DataGridViewColumn In Me.DGVComps.Columns
    Col.HeaderText = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Core.DGV_" & Col.Name)
Next
```

But `My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("Core.DGV_" & Col.Name)` returns `Nothing`.

So is this thing possible? Or do I have to call my resources by name?

PS: I have given this example in VB.NET but I can make it in C# as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Col.HeaderText = My.Resources.Core.ResourceManager.GetString("DGV_" & Col.Name)
```

"Core" is not part of the name of the resource item, but the name of the resource bundle itself.

When using `My.Resources.ResourceManager`, you access the default resource bundle of the project. You can access this in Visual Studio in the properties dialog of the project.